# Remove Language from dropdown

Tags: magento2, multistore, language

How can I remove the language from dropdown,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

just add:

```
<referenceBlock name="store_language" remove="true"/>
```

in:

> /app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

NOTE: **Please don't forget to clear cache after change in  xml files**